# How do you share volumes between Docker containers in an Elastic Beanstalk application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to share data between **two Docker containers** that are running in a multicontainer AWS EC2 instance.

Normally, I would specify the volume as a command flag when I ran the container, ie: `docker run -p 80:80 -p 443:443 --link Widget:Widget --volumes-from Widget --name Nginx1 -d nginx1` to share a volume from Widget to Nginx1.

However, since Elastic Beanstalk requires you to specify your Docker configuration in a `dockerrun.aws.json` file, and then handles running your docker containers internally, I haven't been able to figure out how to share data volumes between containers.

**Note that I'm not trying to share data from the EC2 instance into a Docker container** -- this part seems to work fine; rather, I would like to share data directly from one Docker container to another. I know that docker container volumes are shared with the host at `"/var/lib/docker/volumes/fac362...80535"` etc., but since this location is not static I don't know how I would reference it in the `dockerrun.aws.json` file.

Has anyone found a solution or a workaround?

More info on `dockerrun.aws.json` and the config EB is looking for here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_v2config.html

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same question here. Want to use this feature for sharing compiled assets between rails container and nginx container.

Answer (score 12):

To accomplish what you want, you need to use the `volumesFrom` parameter correctly. You need to make sure to expose the volume with a `VOLUME` command for the container sharing its internal data.

Here's an example Dockerfile which I used to bundle some static files for serving via a webserver:

```
FROM tianon/true
COPY build/ /opt/static
VOLUME ["/opt/static"]
```

Now the relevant parts of the `Dockerrun.aws.json`:

```
{
    "name": "staticfiles",
    "image": "mystaticcontainer",
    "essential": false,
    "memory": "16"
},
{
    "name": "webserver,
    ...
    "volumesFrom" : [
        {
            "sourceContainer": "staticfiles"
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that you don't need any `volumes` entry in the root of the Dockerrun.aws.json file, since the volume is only shared between the two containers, and not persisted on the host. You also don't need any specific `mountPoints` key in the container definition holding the volume to be shared, as the container with `volumesFrom` automatically picks up all the volumes from the referred container. In this example, all the files in `/opt/static` in the `staticfiles` container will also be available to the `webserver` container at the same location.

Comment: does it mean staticfiles container should be always up and running?

Answer (score 2):

From [the AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_data_volumes.html) I found this:

> You can define one or more volumes on a container, and then use the
>   volumesFrom parameter  in a different container definition (within the
>   same task) to mount all of the volumes from the sourceContainer at
>   their originally defined mount points.
>
> The volumesFrom parameter applies to volumes defined in the task
>   definition, and those that are built into the image with a Dockerfile.

Comment: Kyle, could make the linking but the folder is empty after being mounted. It seems that ECS service deletes all the data in the `VOLUME` folder :(

Comment: Hrmm yeah, I feel like we might have tried volumesFrom without success.

Comment: I have used this "type" of mounting with the docker engine alone and it works like a charm. Maybe we have some luck in the AWS Forum ? Or maybe this is the expected behaviour.

Comment: Kyle, I post a question on the AWS forum. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=677566#677566

Comment: Note that you do not need the "volumes" section alongside the "containerDefinitions". The example in the docs will actually wipe out the volume in your data container. Just specifying volumesFrom is enough.

Comment: I'd love to do it this way, haven't had any success thougth

Answer (score 0):

You would need to specify a `dockerVolumeConfiguration` in your Dockerrun.aws.json file.  That's how we accomplished this.  Which essentially gets pushed through to ECS.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-volumes.html

Here is a snippet of my .json file

```
 "volumes": [
    {
      "name": "shared-data",
      "dockerVolumeConfiguration": {
          "scope": "shared",
          "driver": "local",
          "autoprovision": false
      }
    } 
  ],

  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "api",
      "image": "account.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/api:latest",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 128,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 5000,
          "containerPort": 3050
        }
      ],
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "shared-data",
          "containerPath": "/var/area_data"
        }
      ]
    },
```